# What does "seed one's picks" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/EFeEAtXdzFU). It is at 9 minute and 15 second.

> Like, you might ask the English major down the hall who roots for a rival basketball team to read over your essay. But you are not going to ask her to **seed** **your picks** for March Madness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_%28sports%29) has an article about the word *seed* in the context of sports:

> A **seed** is a competitor or team in a sport or other tournament who is given a preliminary ranking for the purposes of the draw. Players/teams are "planted" into the bracket in a manner that is typically intended so that the best do not meet until later in the competition. The term was first used in tennis, and is based on the idea of laying out a tournament ladder by arranging slips of paper with the names of players on them the way seeds or seedlings are arranged in a garden: smaller plants up front, larger ones behind.

*To seed* means to come up with the arrangement of teams in the [bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(tournament)) - in other words, to “plant” the different teams.

Answer (score 0):

**Seed your picks** here is used as a metaphor and means someone else is laying the foundation or doing all the work while you'll get the benefit from the results.
(Someone planting the seeds but you get to harvest/pick the fruit)